# Magento, passing product name to contact form

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, magento, content-management-system

Hello from Magento beginer,i'm poor in knowledge of terms and names but i will try hard to explain this as much clear as i can.

I'm currently working on configuration of *Magento Contact Form* to be able to collect some data from users on **Product View Page**.
To be more interesting, the form will have also to send some data about the product on which page admin puts it, concretely *Product name*
Not all products will have this form, only products that are available for supply in different (currently unavailable) colors and sizes.
I copied Magento Contact Form to my `Layout->Templates->contact->form.phtml`. Embedded it in one of the products page, putting in :  

`Magento Admin Panel-Catalog-Menage Categories-OneOfTheProducts-edit-Custom layout update`
folowing reference xml:

```
<reference> 
  <block type="core/template" name="customer_request"  
   template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Tested it and it works, still admin has to do this xml placing in many products Custom layout update text box, but that's not part of this question.
Magento form has following fields: name, email, telephone, comment.
However i need to send one more parameter to `postAction` action of `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`, and that is Product name.

**QUESTION**
How can i obtain Product name in Contact form from Product page, can this child block element be aware of Page content in which is being embedded? Is there some global function in Magento i can use and how to pass this parameter to controller, should i use hidden input field or else...?

*Any reference or code snippet will mean a world to me*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

In `form.phtml` added this snippet of code to new hidden field value, it retrieves URL key/values of the current page, then it loads model object passing the value of "id":

```
<?php $productId=$this->getRequest()->getParams();   
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
$_product = $model->load($productId["id"]);   
echo $_product->getName(); ?>
```

Added new var to email template referencing that hidden field value,
also this part of code will be good candidate to be placed in helpers class.

Comment: I must correct this to use session instead of hidden field before Alan Storm arrest me. :D

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the Magento registry:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

This would have the efficiency of not having to load another database Model resulting with load of the database. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156609/magento-mageregistrycurrent-product-efficient) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12036214/3376305).