# How to pass a result in phtml file from controller Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am submitting a form and getting result from model.I want to display the result in phtml file ie the whole collection after submitting need to be in phtml file

Here is my code

> Controller

```
        $this->loadLayout();

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    { 
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $data = array();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('searchservice/service')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('compstate',array('eq'=>$post['input1']));

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('searchservice')->__('Displaying Your Result'));
        $this->renderLayout();

    }
```

I want data in an aaray returned from collection filter and use in phtml with foreach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use magento registry for setting and getting values as:

**set a value** (in controller)

```
Mage::register('var_name',$var_value);
```

**get a value** (in phtml/view)

```
$var_value = Mage::registry('var_name');
```

more you can find at

http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157176/725306

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found
in Controller:

```
Mage::register('data', $collection);
```

in view

```
$data = Mage::registry('data');
```

so the code becomes

```
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    { 
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $data = array();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('searchservice/service')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('compstate',array('eq'=>$post['input1']));
        foreach ($collection as $record) 
        {
            $data[] = $record->getProfileurl();
        }
        Mage::register('data', $data);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('searchservice')->__('Displaying Your Result'));
        $this->renderLayout();

    }
```

Comment: i'd just answered it before you